# How to change output format of npm ll?

Tags: node.js, shell, npm

I need to provide my client with all dependencies of our projects (library name + github / npm url). I can do this easily with just `npm ll` inside every project. But this gives me a tree-structured output. Is there a way to change this output to a table?

I've read the documentation of npm ll command and I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all else fails, you can extract what you need using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

`npm ll --json | jq -r 'recurse(.dependencies[]) | [.name, .version, .repository.url?] | @csv'`

Sample output:

```
"express","4.16.4","git+https://github.com/expressjs/express.git"
"accepts","1.3.5","git+https://github.com/jshttp/accepts.git"
"mime-types","2.1.22","git+https://github.com/jshttp/mime-types.git"
"mime-db","1.38.0","git+https://github.com/jshttp/mime-db.git"
"negotiator","0.6.1","git+https://github.com/jshttp/negotiator.git"
```

Comment: Thanks this really helped me. Just to complete more your answer I added this to create a custom script in my package.json and remove duplicates lines.
```"get-licenses": "npm ll --json 2>/dev/null| jq -r 'recurse(.dependencies[]) | [.name, .version, .repository.url?, .license] | @csv' | sort | uniq > *${npm_package_name}.csv*"```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure it fully answers the question, but you can always rework the output to something more manageable - for instance a script such as:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# list packages and remove tree structure prefix + "deduped" suffix (keep only module@version)
data=($(npm ls | sed 's/^[┬├│─└ ]*//g' | sed 's/deduped$//g'))
for module in ${data[*]}
do
  # split on @ only when it separates module and version
  # (not the @ prefix on @username/module@version)
  split=($(echo $module | sed -r 's/^(.+)@/\1 /'))
  # an example display
  printf "%-30s%10s https://www.npmjs.org/packages/%s\n" ${split[0]} ${split[1]} ${split[0]}
done
```

Comment: Hi this might work but I'm getting this: 
./test.sh: Bad substitution before entering the loop.

Comment: Errr, weird. I pasted this from a working script, but maybe the characters' encoding messed up between your/my browser and/or your/my editor? I mean these: `┬├│─└`. What I did to get them was trying a `npm ls`, then copy-pasting them directly from the shell output. Or you can try an exclusion pattern instead: `s/^[^a-zA-Z0-9@_\.-]*//g` (although this is way more unpredictable as I'm not sure what is allowed or not as a starting character in an NPM module name).